# reactjs render image dynamically

Tags: reactjs

To be clear:

```
<img src={require('../styles/myimage.jpg')} />
```

works fine. But I want to get this path dynamically as a string from api. In my parent component I fetch it and pass to child:

```
<img src={require(this.props.image)} />
```

In this case **this.props.image** is the same as  **'../styles/myimage.jpg'**. But it does not work for me and throw this error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module "."

How can I fix it?

The directory tree is (I am trying to fetch myimage.jpg from image.js)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enjsF.png):
And webpack config: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahbL7.png)

Comment: Make sure that the props have a value when your render is called

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  I even tried conditional rendering, so I make request with fetch...setState({image: data, loadImage: true}) and then in my child component i check if loadImage is true then I render  "this.props.loadImage ? <img src={require(this.props.image)} /> : null".

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple test, move styles path with contains yours jpg files to same path of your component and try this path in props:

```
props.image = './styles/myimage.jpg'
```

then

```
<img src={require(this.props.image)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment what you can do is in your render method try this :

```
if (!this.props.image) return false;
```